# How could I insert date from mktime into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mktime

I want to insert date in format `m-d` into database. I used this code

```
$date1=date("m-d",mktime(0,0,0,$month1 ,$day1,1));
```

The date is inserted as `0000-00-00` in MySQL, and I don't know why.

I want to do that to compare that date stored in MySQL with current month and day. How can this be done?

Comment: Fancy showing us where you actually perform the insertion?

Answer (score 1):

mysql date must be of the form Y-m-d . Building a date with m-d form brings an invalid date.

If you want to compare only month or day, you can use mysql MONTH and DAYOFMONTH functions. For example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(datecol) = {$month1} AND DAYOFMONTH(datecol) = {$day1}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date1=date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,$month1 ,$day1,1));
```

Comment: Although the solution is technically correct, this answer explains precisely nothing.